# error "Invalid parenthesized assignment pattern" background info

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my [React](https://reactjs.org/) project, I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: ... Invalid parenthesized assignment pattern
const add = (a, b) = { return a + b; };
             ^
```

**I do understand the error**, but I am surprised that I could not find any **information** about it.

- Where does it come from ?
- Where is it documented ?

#### What I want to understand

I do understand the problem here *(the '>' is missing in this arrow function)*, but I wonder (1) where this error comes from exactly (not the Browser?), and (2) where could I find information about it.

The error message obviously interprets this as a wrong assignment, not as a wrong arrow function:

```
const add = (a, b) = { return a + b; };
// error ----^
// actually wrong --^
```

#### Where it obviously does *not* come from:

If I write the same statement in the **NodeJs CLI**, I get:

```
const add = (a,b) = { return ''; }
            ^^^^^
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

in the **Firefox console**:

```
SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand side
```

Note that I am using Firefox for development, but the error message during development is different than the error message when I try the same in the Firefox console (`Invalid parenthesized assignment pattern` vs. `SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand side`)

Comment: It comes from [babel's parser](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwTAvDAFHANDARgSlRgG8YAnAUygFcyx4YBqPAbhgF8Wg&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.11.6&externalPlugins=) . Error messages are not necessarily standardized.

Comment: The "rules" for a syntax error can be tricky to find. After all, since it's a syntax error, we don't necessarily know how the parser sees the code. If the parser parses `(a, b)` as the grouping operator, then that operator delegates the valid assignment target check to its containing expression. `a,b` would be the comma operator, which cannot be assigned to: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-comma-operator-static-semantics-assignmenttargettype

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the ES6 arrow function, you have to define **=>**

```
const add = (a, b) = { return a + b; }; // here you missed arrow for function **=>**

const add = (a, b) **=>** { return a + b; }; //modified by adding **=>**
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, you missed the point. As I said: I do understand the problem here "the '>' is missing". The question was about where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from the [Babel parser](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-parser).

The text is defined in [babel / packages / babel-parser / src / parse-error / standard-errors.ts](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/packages/babel-parser/src/parse-error/standard-errors.ts#L152):

```
InvalidParenthesizedAssignment: "Invalid parenthesized assignment pattern.",
```

#### Documentation

These kind of errors are *(apparently)* not documented on a user level, but there is some explanation in the source code in [babel / packages / babel-parser / src / util / expression-scope.ts](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/packages/babel-parser/src/util/expression-scope.ts):

[line 32](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/packages/babel-parser/src/util/expression-scope.ts#L32):

```md
- MaybeArrowParameterDeclaration
  A scope that represents ambiguous arrow head e.g. `(x)`. Errors will be recorded
  alongside parent scopes and thrown when `ExpressionScopeHandler#validateAsPattern`
  is called.
```

[line 164](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/packages/babel-parser/src/util/expression-scope.ts#L164):

```md
* A parenthesized identifier (or type assertion) in LHS can be ambiguous because the assignment
* can be transformed to an assignable later, but not vice versa:
* For example, in `([(a) = []] = []) => {}`, we think `(a) = []` is an LHS in `[(a) = []]`,
* an LHS within `[(a) = []] = []`. However the LHS chain is then transformed by toAssignable,
* and we should throw assignment `(a)`, which is only valid in LHS. Hence we record the
* location of parenthesized `(a)` to current scope if it is one of MaybeArrowParameterDeclaration
* and MaybeAsyncArrowParameterDeclaration
```